# Selenium2: Taking screenshots with selenium grid 2

Tags: screenshot, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

Is it possible to take screenshots using selenium grid 2?  The RemoteWebDriver class does not implement the TakesScreenshot interface.

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RemoteWebDriver` must be augmented before you can use the screenshot capability. As you have no doubt already found, attempting to cast without augmenting results in an exception.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver( ... );
driver           = new Augmenter().augment( driver );
( (TakesScreenshot)driver ).getScreenshotAs( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks Mike... Code needed a bit of fixing but it works great :)

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for it
  driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a wrapper class that extends RemoteWebDriver and implement TakeScreenshot interface something like below in java.

```
public class ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver extends RemoteWebDriver implements TakesScreenshot 
{ 
    public ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(URL url, DesiredCapabilities dc) { 
        super(url, dc); 
    } 
    @Override
    public <X> X getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) throws WebDriverException { 
        if ((Boolean)getCapabilities().getCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT)) {
            return target.convertFromBase64Png(execute(DriverCommand.SCREENSHOT).getValue().toString()); 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks nilesh.  I think the other approach (Augmenter) is cleaner tho. :)

Comment: True. I had this in place before Augmenter became part of the API.